# prototype value does not update for every instance in js, why?

Tags: javascript

if I set a prototype value and make two instances

then update the prototype value in one instance

now other instance prototype value does not update, why?

code is

```
var A = function() {

}
A.prototype.u = 2;

var a = new A();

var b = new A();

a.u = 4
alert(a.u) // 4
alert(b.u) // 2
```

it's so unreasonable, it's prototype value not this value. right?

Comment: When doing assignment, the prototype chain isn't used, the property is only searched for on the object itself and if not found, a new property is added, masking the one on the prototype.

Comment: @RobG so I cannot update a prototype value in method, like global var?

Comment: Yes you can, but not the way you are trying to do it. You need to assign to `A.prototype.u` as in Quentin's answer.

Comment: @RobG do you think about to set prototype = {u:[11]}, then change it in instance, just not to type constructor name and prototype

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You aren't "updating the prototype value". You are writing the new value to the local object and not to the prototype chain. The local property masks the one higher up the chain.

`alert(a.u);` looks at `a`, finds a `u` and alerts it.

`alert(b.u);` looks at `b`, doesn't find a `u`, looks up the prototype chain, finds a `u` and alerts it.

Compare:

```js
var A = function() {

}
A.prototype.u = 2;

var a = new A();

var b = new A();

a.u = 4;
A.prototype.u = 6;
alert(a.u);
alert(b.u);
```

Comment: `alert(b.u) // 2` <-- 6?

Comment: 6 is right, since b.u is searched first -> not found -> prototype is then searched -> found -> 6. @Quentin's answer says 2 which is not right

Comment: @Quentin if I write

    a.x = function(){A.prototype.u = 6}

it doest not work, why?

Comment: @Roy — Because you are either still masking it locally or because you don't call the method before you test the value of `u`.

Comment: @Roy—that just assigns a function to *a.x*. Until you call it (i.e. `a.x()`), the value of *A.prototype.u* won't change.

Comment: @Quentin yes , I forgot to execute it, many thinks, and I found a new way to update prototype value, it's array, if I type A.prototype = {u:[11]} then var a and b = new A(); a.u[0] = 2;alert a.u[0] and b.u[0], the value all will be 2, :)